# Matplotlib installation problems

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to install matplotlib in a remote linux machine, and I am a normal user there.

I downlodad the source and run

```
python setup.py build
```

but I get errors, related with numpy, which is not installed, so I decieded to install it first. I download and compile with

```
python setup.py build
```

My question now is, how do I tell to teh matplotlib installation where the numpy files have been installed?

Thanks

Comment: `matplotlib` should be able to find `numpy` once it's installed correctly (since it goes into lib/site-packages) ? If it does not, which error message do you get?

Comment: Have you actually tried to install numpy? "build" just... builds it, but doesn't actually installs it somewhere usable by Python (and so, undetectable for matplotlib)

Comment: sorry, i did not explain it correctly. my questions reduces to:

after i build numpy, and as I am a normal user, I can install it onto some directory. afterwards, how do i tell matplotlib where numpy nas been installed?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? You can't import numpy???

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a user and not root on the remote machine, it may be that your environement is not configured correctly.
Check that you can load numpy from the interperter.

> > import numpy

If that fails, you may need to add its installed location to sys.path

import sys
sys.path.append("\user\local\numpy")
import numpy

Once you know where it is and can get it to load in the interperter, you can modify your site.py to add the path automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I wonder if you just need the numpy directory in PYTHONPATH before executing the installer.

```
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/numpy"
```

Then run the build command.